# How to remove a removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I learned about Riemann’s theorem on removable singularities, which states:

> Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a open subset, $a \in D$ and let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on $D\setminus\{a\}$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $a$
> 2. $f$ is continuously extendable over $a$
> 3. There exists a neighborhood of $a$ such that $f$ is bounded
> 4. $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to a} (z-a) f(z) = 0$

Because of this theorem I know that a function can be extendable over a, but how does the extending work in practice?

I tried on this example. Let
$$
f(z) := \frac{\sin(z)-z}{z^2}.
$$
First I tried 4. to see if it is extendable.
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} z \frac{\sin(z)-z}{z^2} 
= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin(z)}{z} - 1 
= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\cos(z)}{1} - 1 
= 0
$$

Thus $f$ is holomorphically extendable over $0$.

Now I want to find the value $f(0)$
My idea would be to use a taylor series.
I can't do the Taylor series of $f$ in $0$, but I can do the Taylor series of $\sin(z)-z$ in $0$:
$$
\sin(z)-z 
= -z + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$

Now I can divide the taylor series of $\sin(z)-z$ by $z^2$:
$$
\frac{\sin(z)-z}{z^2} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}
$$

Now if I take this Taylor series and let $z \to 0$, then I get
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} 
= 0
$$

This would mean, if I define $f(0):=0$, then $f$ is continuous and thus by 2. also holomorphic.

I have 3 Questions:

(i)
First, is the way I solved this correct?

(ii)
Is there another method to do this?

(iii)
In this case the denominator was a (Taylor) polynomial which was the reason why I was able to find the Taylor series of $f$. How should one approach the problem if the denominator is not a polynomial? Is there a more general way?

Comment: Just take the limit $\lim _{z \rightarrow a} f(z)$ and define $f(a)$ to be this limit. The existence of the limit is guaranteed by the four equivalent conditions.

Answer (score 1):

(i) What you did is exactly what I would have done.

(ii/iii) To say something slightly less trivial, notice that if $f$ is holomorphic (indeed, even continuous) then
$f(a) = \lim_{z \to a} f(z)$. You computed this limit with a power series, but if your function $f$ is more complicated, then you'll have to resort to your bag of tricks from calculus.

Of course, if you're feeling lazy, for any reasonable function a computer algebra system like [sage](https://sagemath.org) can also compute the limit for you. So in the real world, figuring out what the extension should be is a completely effective problem.

---

I hope this helps ^_^